# Transform dataframe to show first, second, and third changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
records_A = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1001,1001,1001,1001,1002,1002,1002,1003,1003,1003,1004,1005,1006,1006,1006,1006,1006], 
'location': ['NJ','OH','OH','OH','HI','AK','HI','NC','NJ','NJ','PA','UT','AZ','AZ','AZ','AZ','AZ'],
                     'date': ['1/1','4/1','6/1','7/11','1/1','4/1','6/1','1/1','4/1','6/1','1/1','1/1','1/1','2/2','7/3','9/9','12/10']})
```

I would love to transform it to see a single row for each id, with columns showing the first, second, and third locations, along with the start date of each of those locations, if they exist. Bonus points if the code could accommodate even more than 3 locations (ie., add and name as many columns as necessary).

Expected output would be:

| id | 1st location | 1st location start date | 2nd location | 2ndlocation start date | 3rdlocation | 3rd location start date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | NJ | 1/1 | OH | 4/1 | nan | nan |
| 1002 | HI | 1/1 | AK | 4/1 | HI | 6/1 |
| 1003 | NC | 1/1 | NJ | 4/1 | nan | nan |
| 1004 | PA | 1/1 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1005 | UT | 1/1 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1006 | AZ | 1/1 | nan | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: why does HI show up twice for id 1002?

Comment: There could be a scenario where the person moves back and forth. E.g., in this case, say someone moved from HI to AK and then back to HI.